# Сокрытие символов при вводе пароля

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Я сделал функцию для ввода логина/пароля и хотел, чтобы пароль скрывался звездочками, а выводились бы логин и пароль в формате `login:password`. Но в конце выводится и мусор - лишние символы - см. скриншоты консоли. Почему это происходит? Как избавиться от этого?

**Вопросы**: как лучше сохранять пароль, не отображать его при вводе и создать массив с размером, равным кол-ву символов в пароле? Как возможно реализовать это на C++?

Вот код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void sign_in() {
    const int n = 50;
    char login[n];
    char *pass = new char[0];
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    std::cout << "Your login: ";
    std::cin.getline(login, n);
    std::cout << "Your password: ";
    while ((c = _getch()) != '\r')
    {
        pass[i++] = c;
        _putch('*');
    }
    std::cout << endl << login << ":" << pass << endl;
}
int main(){
    sign_in();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: результат]

[image: результат 2]

Comment: Что-то я не до конца понял Ваши намерения, объясните детальнее, если можно?

Comment: А, Ваша проблема в том, что в массиве, который предназначен для пароля, мусор какой-то остается - остаточные символы?

Comment: @Jenssen да, я не знаю как от этого избавитсься и из-за чего это в принципе

Comment: Сейчас объясню, подождите моего ответа)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void sign_in() 
{
    std::string       login;
    std::vector<char> password;

    char c;

    std::cout << "Enter login: ";
    std::cin >> login;
    std::cout << "Enter password: ";
    while ((c = _getch()) != '\r')
    {
        password.push_back(c);
        _putch('*');
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << login << " : ";

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < password.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << password[i];
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    sign_in();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Вот такую модификацию Вашего кода я предлагаю, теперь объясню в деталях построчно:

1. Некоторые заголовочные файлы я убрал, они не нужны. Добавилась директива `#include <vector>` - этот заголовок предоставляет возможность работы с последовательным контейнером `std::vector`. О нем Вы можете прочитать, например, [здесь](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) и [здесь](http://cppstudio.com/post/8453/).
2. Я убрал `using namespace std;`. Когда будете писать большие проекты, у Вас будет много пространств имен и Вы поймете, что такая вещь, как `using namespace`, вообще говоря, неудобна. Приучайтесь смолоду;) Пишите `std::` перед всем, где требуется.
3. Аргументы в `main` необязательны, это я так, по привычке. `EXIT_SUCCESS` = `0`.

Переходим к рассмотрению функции `void sign_in()`:

4. `login` теперь имеет тип `std::string`. Все-таки на C++ пишем, отвыкайте от массивов, строк в C-стиле. Они менее безопасны;) Прочитать о типе `string` можно [здесь](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) и [здесь](http://cppstudio.com/post/6110/).
5. `password` - массив типа `vector`, хранящий `char`-ы. Изначально массив пуст.
6. `password.push_back(c);` добавление нового символа пароля в конец массива.
7. `std::size_t` - целочисленный тип данных, можно написать просто `int i = 0`.

Что касается Вашего кода, то вот таким образом `char *pass = new char[0];` Вы создаете динамический массив на `0` элементов типа `char`. Записывать туда что-то, мягко говоря, не очень хорошо. И потом, раз вы создали массив посредством оператора `new[]`, то удалите его с помощью `delete[]`. Также могу добавить, что современный C++ позволяет почти полностью (если не совсем) отказаться в клиентском коде от использования обычных указателей. А заменяются они т.н. *интеллектуальными указателями* (изучите их).

Еще немного не понял Ваш комментарий относительно сокрытия пароля. Если Вы хотите, чтобы даже звездочек не было, то можете сделать так `_putch(' ');` вместо `_putch('*');` и будут у Вас пробелы печататься. Плюс можно сделать, чтобы еще и курсор не сдвигался.

Comment: А что всё-таки означают аргументы в main?

Comment: @JohnyJay вот тут смотрите http://cppstudio.com/post/421/ все подробно и понятно

Comment: system("pause") не нужен. Просто запускать нужно по Ctrl+F5, а не по F5.

Comment: @KoVadim убрал, спасибо за замечание. Тут и правда не нужно.

Comment: @Jenssen без `#include "stdafx.h"` работать не будет - так требует Visual Studio

Comment: @JohnyJay тут надо настройки проекта смотреть, работать будет и без него. Ничего ужасного, разумеется, не случится при добавлении этого хедера)

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант для случая, когда пароль требуется хранить как нуль-терминированную строку (в этом примере длина пароля не превосходит 10 символов):

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

void readPassword(char * pass, int maxLen) {
 int len = 0;
 while (true) {
  char c = _getch();
  if (c == '\r')
   break;
  if (len == maxLen-1)
   break;
  pass[len++] = c;
  _putch('*');
 }
 pass[len] = '\0';
}

int main() {
 char password[11];
 std::cout << "Enter password: ";
 readPassword(password, 11);
 std::cout << "\nYour password is: " << password;
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Небольшая доработка ответа пользователя Jens.
Добавлена "перегонка" vector в string, если требуется работы только со string

```
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    void sign_in() {
        string       login;
        vector<char> password;

        char c;

        cout << "Enter login: ";
        cin >> login;
        cout << "Enter password: ";
        while ((c = _getch()) != '\r') {
            password.push_back(c);
            _putch('*');
        }
        // "перегонка" из vector в string
        string pass(password.begin(), password.end());

        cout << endl << login << " : " << pass << endl;
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        sign_in();

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).